# How to Show this HTML text in text view Android

Tags: android

I have this HTML string

"Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.indiacom.com/\"\u003eIndiacom Yellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"

How can i show this in text view ?

Html.fromhtml() is not wrking.

Comment: define it in `string.xml` if it is static. If it is dynamic then do like this `Html.fromhtml("Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.indiacom.com/\"\u003eIndiacom Yellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e");`

Comment: Html.fromhtml() is not working , its giving an exception

Comment: post your question with the **error** you got

Comment: Try to html data to WebView instead of TextView for proper html content shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
String value = "<html> <a href=\"http://example.com/\">example.com</a> </html>";
tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSite);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to display Html string in your app:

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""http://www.indiacom.com/"\">" Indiacom Yellow Pages "</a>"));
tv1.setClickable(true);
tv1.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```